# SQL Server: Convert some rows to columns with joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert some rows to columns in SQL Server, but all of the joined tables are confusing me.  I'm not sure where or how to add the CASE or PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @BeginDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
SET @BeginDateTime = '20170901'
SET @EndDateTime = '20170922'

SELECT DISTINCT     
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BILL_TABLE.srvc_thru_dt, 101) AS DischargeDate, PATIENT_TABLE.[Master Patient ID] AS MedRec, PATIENT_TABLE.[Hospital #] AS VisitID, LOCATION_TABLE.loc_ds AS Location, PERSON_TABLE.lst_nm AS LastName, PERSON_TABLE.fst_nm AS FirstName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PATIENT_TABLE.[Date of Birth], 101) AS DOB, PATIENT_TABLE.ZIP, DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_rank_no) AS DxRank, CODING_TABLE.icd9_code AS Dx

FROM         BILL_TABLE INNER JOIN
             PATIENT_TABLE ON BILL_TABLE.vst_int_id = PATIENT_TABLE.[Visit #] INNER JOIN
             PERSON_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.psn_int_id = PERSON_TABLE.psn_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             LOCATION_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.loc_lvl_5_id = LOCATION_TABLE.loc_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             DIAGNOSIS_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.[Visit #] = DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.vst_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             CODING_TABLE ON DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.icd9_int_id = CODING_TABLE.icd9_int_id

WHERE  (bil_cre_dt >= @BeginDateTime) AND 
    bil_cre_dt < @EndDateTime AND
    srvc_cd_int_id IN (20329, 21912, 20332, 20333, 20335, 20337, 20339, 20340, 20341, 20343) AND
    DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty != 'A'
```

This gives me the following results:

```
 DischargeDate  | MedRec | VisitID | Location | LastName | FirstName |    DOB    |  ZIP  | DxRank |  Dx
 ---------------|--------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|-----------|-------|--------|------   
 09/20/2017     |  12345 |  111100 |    203   |  TESTER  |    JEFF   | 01/01/1984| 90210 |   P1   | 4005A
 09/20/2017     |  12345 |  111100 |    203   |  TESTER  |    JEFF   | 01/01/1984| 90210 |   S2   | R42
 09/20/2017     |  12345 |  111100 |    203   |  TESTER  |    JEFF   | 01/01/1984| 90210 |   S3   | E860
 09/21/2017     |  23456 |  111101 |    205   |  TESTER  |    BILL   | 02/02/2007| 45321 |   P1   | N390
```

I need the results to look like this:

```
DischargeDate  | MedRec | VisitID | Location | LastName | FirstName |    DOB    |  ZIP  |  P1  |  S2  |  S3
---------------|--------|---------|----------|----------|-----------|-----------|-------|------|------|-------   
09/20/2017     |  12345 |  111100 |    203   |  TESTER  |    JEFF   | 01/01/1984| 90210 |4005A |  R42 | E860
09/21/2017     |  23456 |  111101 |    205   |  TESTER  |    BILL   | 02/02/2007| 45321 |N39   |  NULL| NULL
```

Comment: which database engine you are using exactly..sql server or my sql ..?

Comment: It's SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run this query but I think this should work -

```
DECLARE @BeginDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
SET @BeginDateTime = '20170901'
SET @EndDateTime = '20170922'

;WITH PIVOTDATA
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT     
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BT.srvc_thru_dt, 101) AS DischargeDate, 
        PT.[Master Patient ID] AS MedRec, 
        PT.[Hospital #] AS VisitID, 
        LT.loc_ds AS Location, 
        PT1.lst_nm AS LastName, 
        PT1.fst_nm AS FirstName, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PT.[Date of Birth], 101) AS DOB, 
        PT.ZIP, 
        DT.ICD9_diag_ty + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT.ICD9_rank_no) AS DxRank, 
        CT.icd9_code AS Dx
    FROM BILL_TABLE  BT
    INNER JOIN PATIENT_TABLE PT
    ON BT.vst_int_id = PT.[Visit #] 
    INNER JOIN PERSON_TABLE PT1
    ON PT.psn_int_id = PT1.psn_int_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION_TABLE LT 
    ON PT.loc_lvl_5_id = LT.loc_int_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DIAGNOSIS_TABLE DT 
    ON PT.[Visit #] = DT.vst_int_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CODING_TABLE CT
    ON DT.icd9_int_id = CT.icd9_int_id
    WHERE  (bil_cre_dt >= @BeginDateTime)  
       AND bil_cre_dt < @EndDateTime
       AND srvc_cd_int_id IN (20329, 21912, 20332, 20333, 20335, 20337, 20339, 20340, 20341, 20343)
       AND DT.ICD9_diag_ty != 'A'
)
SELECT 
    DischargeDate,
    MedRec,
    VisitID,
    Location,
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    DOB,
    ZIP,
    P1, S2, S3
FROM PIVOTDATA
PIVOT(MAX(Dx) FOR DxRank IN (P1, S2, S3)) AS P;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @BeginDateTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
SET @BeginDateTime = '20170901'
SET @EndDateTime = '20170922'

SELECT DISTINCT     
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BILL_TABLE.srvc_thru_dt, 101) AS DischargeDate, PATIENT_TABLE.[Master Patient ID] AS MedRec, PATIENT_TABLE.[Hospital #] AS VisitID, LOCATION_TABLE.loc_ds AS Location,
 PERSON_TABLE.lst_nm AS LastName, PERSON_TABLE.fst_nm AS FirstName, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), PATIENT_TABLE.[Date of Birth], 101) AS DOB,
  PATIENT_TABLE.ZIP, 
CASE when (DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_rank_no))='P1' then CODING_TABLE.icd9_code END P1,
CASE WHEN (DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_rank_no))='S2' then CODING_TABLE.icd9_code END S2,
CASE WHEN (DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_rank_no))='S3' then CODING_TABLE.icd9_code END S3
FROM         BILL_TABLE INNER JOIN
             PATIENT_TABLE ON BILL_TABLE.vst_int_id = PATIENT_TABLE.[Visit #] INNER JOIN
             PERSON_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.psn_int_id = PERSON_TABLE.psn_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             LOCATION_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.loc_lvl_5_id = LOCATION_TABLE.loc_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             DIAGNOSIS_TABLE ON PATIENT_TABLE.[Visit #] = DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.vst_int_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
             CODING_TABLE ON DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.icd9_int_id = CODING_TABLE.icd9_int_id

WHERE  (bil_cre_dt >= @BeginDateTime) AND 
    bil_cre_dt < @EndDateTime AND
    srvc_cd_int_id IN (20329, 21912, 20332, 20333, 20335, 20337, 20339, 20340, 20341, 20343) AND
    DIAGNOSIS_TABLE.ICD9_diag_ty != 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a thought which might help you out .try this queries.

**Your Result Data**

```
select * into #Result from
(
select '09/20/2017'DischargeDate  ,'12345' MedRec ,'111100' VisitID ,'203' Location ,'TESTER' LastName ,'JEFF' FirstName ,'01/01/1984'  DOB    ,'90210'  ZIP  ,'P1'DxRank ,'4005A'  Dx
union all
select '09/20/2017',  '12345',  '111100',    '203',  'TESTER',    'JEFF', '01/01/1984', '90210',   'S2', 'R42'
union all
select '09/20/2017',  '12345',  '111100',    '203',  'TESTER',    'JEFF', '01/01/1984', '90210',   'S3', 'E860'
union all
select '09/21/2017',  '23456',  '111101',    '205',  'TESTER',    'BILL', '02/02/2007', '45321',   'P1', 'N390'
)as a
```

**Static Query**

```
;with cte as (
select * from (
select MedRec,DxRank ,Dx from #result
)as b
pivot(max(Dx)for DxRank in([P1],[S2],[S3]) )as a
)
select distinct b.DischargeDate  , b.MedRec , b.VisitID , b.Location , b.LastName , b.FirstName ,b.DOB,[P1],[S2],[S3] from cte a
inner join 
(select DischargeDate  , MedRec , VisitID , Location , LastName , FirstName ,    DOB ,ZIP     from #Result)b
on b.MedRec=a.Medrec
```

**Dynamic Query**

```
Declare @columns varchar(max)=stuff((select distinct ','+Dxrank from #result for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Declare @Query nvarchar(max)
set @Query=';with cte as (
select * from (
select MedRec,DxRank ,Dx from #result
)as b
pivot(max(Dx)for DxRank in('+@columns+') )as a
)
select distinct b.DischargeDate  , b.MedRec , b.VisitID , b.Location , b.LastName , b.FirstName ,    b.DOB,'+ @columns+  ' from cte a
inner join 
(select DischargeDate  , MedRec , VisitID , Location , LastName , FirstName ,    DOB      from #Result)b
on b.MedRec=a.Medrec'

print @Query
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```